# Unwrap t.co links using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter

How can I get the target URL for a Twitter t.co link that has been captured via the Twitter API using JavaScript.

e.g. http://t.co/NJwI2ugt

Comment: What does such a link look like?

Comment: http://support.twitter.com/entries/109623

Comment: @Camsoft: From inside the browser or from inside some server-side javascript?

Answer (score 2):

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/duotrigesimal/XB8Uf/

It makes a request to the api at LongURL (http://longurl.org/api#expand-url) to get the expanded url.

I'm also using jQuery in this example, but you can make it work without if needed.

```
var tests = [
    'http://t.co/NJwI2ugt', 
    'http://www.google.com' //nothing should happen
];

for(i in tests) {

    var data = {
        url: tests[i],
        format: 'json'
    };

    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://api.longurl.org/v2/expand',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $('#output').append(response['long-url']+'<br>');
        }

    });

}
```