# Unwrap t.co links with R

Tags: r, twitter

I'm looking to unwrap t.co (for Twitter's shortened URL) links using R.

Here's an example of one: http://t.co/Xvb6T3KyHr

Here's the unwrapped URL: http://www.donorschoose.org/project/we-need-technology-in-physical-education/1684466/?utm_source=dc&utm_medium=project&utm_campaign=twitter&rf=twitter-siteshare-2015-09-project-teacher_3103521

There are answers for [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8872232/unwrap-t-co-links-with-python) and [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970663/unwrap-t-co-links-using-javascript), but as far as I can tell none for R.

Comment: `twitteR::decode_short_url("http://t.co/Xvb6T3KyHr")`? `httr::HEAD("http://t.co/Xvb6T3KyHr")$url`?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
twitteR::decode_short_url("http://t.co/Xvb6T3KyHr")
```

or

```
httr::HEAD("http://t.co/Xvb6T3KyHr")$url
```

There's also a package called [`longurl`](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/longurl) from @hrbrmstr. However, it seems as if it doesn't work with t.co links anymore.